# Library dependencies for sbt, org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

What should be added in libraryDependencies for storagelevel in sbt file, I am building spark using sbt tool?

I have my build.sbt file as,

```
name := "Spark Sample"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "1.5.2"
```

I get an error while compiling using sbt tool.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/project_readdirectory/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/project_readdirectory/src/main/scala/query.scala:8: expected class or object definition
[error] org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed Dec 22, 2015 8:38:49 PM
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more context, such as showing the lines surrounding line 8 of `query.scala`? The `StorageLevel` class is part of the `spark-core` artifact, so this is probably not a dependency resolution issue; rather, I suspect it's a problem with your code but cannot say for sure without more context.

Comment: I figured out that i had forgot to mention import, thanks though.

Comment: Can you please use it as an answer?

Comment: Using, import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel and you can use rdd.persist(StorageLevel.storage_level as in documentation).